# How to get the start time of a date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How to get the start time of a date in PostgreSQL? ex- from "2013-07-15 10:10:00" to get "2013-07-15 00:00:00"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you can cast it, but you won't get the "00:00:00" which the OP requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `date_trunc`, eg:

```
psql=> SELECT date_trunc('day',now());
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2016-10-07 00:00:00+11
(1 row)
```

See: [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)